# FullCalendar select all dates in array/list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, fullcalendar, each

I have data coming through for specific dates, and I need to select those dates on the FullCalendar. I am having issues getting those dates selected, however. I've already formatted my incoming dates to match the formatting of the data-date td attributes of the calendar. So - for each date (class .fc-day), if this .fc-day attribute data-date equals a date from the dates list, select that day.

```
var dates = ["2014-10-20", "2014-10-21"];


        $('.fc-day').each(function () {
            var thisdate = $(this).attr('data-date');
            var td = $(this).closest('td');

            if (thisdate == "2014-10-20") {
            //if (thisdate == dates) {
            //if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-date'), dates) !== -1) {
            //if (dates.indexOf(thisdate) >= 0) {
                td.addClass('fc-state-highlight');
            } else {
                td.removeClass('fc-state-highlight');
            }
        });
```

http://jsbin.com/jezidixaji/1/

Comment: works if you use code you commented out `if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-date'), dates) !== -1) {...`

Comment: Tried it, no difference.

Comment: can see the class applied right in the live html

Comment: Did you change something besides commenting/uncommenting? Not working for me. Paste your saved link?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/laxajazoxu/1/edit?html,css,js,output